# What did Kaku mean when he said 'assassins can never find other work'?

Tags: one-piece, japanese-language

In the Enies Lobby Arc of One Piece, Kaku says to Roronoa Zolo 'they say assassins can never find other work' after their fight.

[image: An injured and defeated Kaku from One Piece saying 'they say assassins can never find other work'.]

As a native English speaker, I have never heard this phrase be used before, and a quick web search shows no results. This leads me to believe that it could be a direct translation of a Japanese saying that had no English alternative. But what does it mean?

Comment: Possibly just means what it says:  once you're an assassin, no one wants to hire you for a different kind of job.

Answer (score 3):

The original [seems to be](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1436058024):

> カク:パウリーか…。そうか…困ったわい…。殺し屋という仕事は**潰しがきかん**というのに…

潰しがきく essentially means that (the job) involves transferrable skills, or easy to switch jobs/workplace. Here it is negated and the part literally means "Being an assassin does not train you for other jobs (than assassins)" or "Working as an assassin, I don't have skills for other jobs".

Comment: @Medium you can accept this answer as I don't think there is a better explanation for your question :)